# Webserver overriding page encoding?

Tags: apache, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have pages that I have manually coded in PHP more than 10 years ago.

They are encoded in the old Hebrew encoding - windows-1255

Lately, they were all broken - text is shown as unrecognized UTF-8 characters - diamond with a question mark inside.

When I manually change the encoding in the browser - any browser - the text is displayed correctly.

I thought that maybe the server at my host is forcing UFT-8 encoding. I have change .htaccess to force windows-1255 encoding but it didn't work.

I tried validating the page via W3C and it sees the page as UTF-8

I downloaded XAMPP and ran the server locally and it's still happening.

Has anything changed in the last year(s) in the way that Apache is serving web pages regarding the encoding?

Before I go over all my pages and change their encoding, I would like to know if there is a global "switch" I can flip in order for my pages to display correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the `.htaccess` setting you applied? Also, create a new Hebrew HTML file (not PHP) with no meta charset tag, save it with windows-1255 encoding and put it on your web server.  Does it display correctly in the browser? What `Content-Type` HTTP header does your browser get for this test file?

Comment: Thanks. Some improvements but not solved yet. Clean HTML is displayed correctly. .htaccess lines are **AddDefaultCharset WINDOWS-1255 & php_value default_charset WINDOWS-1255** PHP file is displayed correctly on local machine but not on the server. On the **local machine phpinfo** shows default_charset: Local Value WINDOWS-1255 Master Value UTF-8 **server phpinfo** shows default_charset: Local Value UTF-8 Master Value UTF-8. _Where do I go now?_

Comment: It means there's a difference in configuration between your local setup and the remote server. Since you've already checked `.htaccess`, check for differences in `httpd.conf` and `php.ini` files. Also, is there any common php file (included in all content files) or any calls to `ini_set`? Can you test with a new bare bones php file, without any `include` or `require` statements?

Comment: I programmed a small hello-world.php and it's not working on the server but is ok on my local machine. I have contacted the hosting company and asked for support. Will update. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After much struggling, a kind soul helped me realize that it's not Apache overriding the charset in the header but PHP itself.

Adding

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255');
```

to the top of the PHP file fixed the problem.

As far as I understand the chain is as follows:

1. By default, Apache sends the content with a UTF-8 header
2. If another charset is set in .htaccess, the browser accepts it
3. Then comes PHP and forces the charset in the header as specified by default_charset in php.ini

Anything you define before the page reaches the browser in ignored.

Comment: Note that it doesn't "send the content as UTF-8"… all this does is set a header telling the browser what encoding the content supposedly is in. The actual content doesn't change one bit. It's simply the browser decoding the content with the wrong charset, because it's been instructed wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Changed the answer according to your correction,